# Basic files of extension are suddenly missing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

OK I got a really weird question... my extension is installed at a specific computer and after it worked for few days the extension just stopped working. 
When I checked the background console (at tools->extensions) I saw that it emitted "Failed to load resource" for my background.js file and for a content script file....

Just to be be clear about it, it worked already and after few days it suddenly can't get its basic files... anyone got an idea?

Can a toolbar installation (or something like that) cause such an issue?

Comment: Remove the extension, and install it again. I've experienced the bug a couple of times, and it seems like a failed extension update. The extension folder was completely empty.

Answer (score 0):

You may be referencing an old extension id to retrieve your files...

Be sure you're always using [chrome.extension.getUrl](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL) and never storing file paths, because your extension can change over time for various reasons.